# Как исключить выполнение двух (одного и того же) Python скриптов одновременно?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть скрипт, который запускается в заданное время и существует большая вероятность его повторного запуска, даже когда последний его запуск не завершился. Можно ли заблокировать его повторный запуск, пока он еще выполняется? Пишу под виндовс, но будет использоваться на линукс сервере.
Нашел такое решение, но еще не тестил, тк пока скрипт еще не дописан:

```
try:
    WMI = GetObject('winmgmts:')

    processes = WMI.InstancesOf('Win32_Process')

    processes_list = \
        [process.Properties_('Name').Value for process in processes]


    if processes_list.count('urtvospoll.exe') > 1:
        message = wx.MessageDialog(None, 
            'Программа Urtvos Poll уже запущена',
            'Ошибка', wx.OK | wx.ICON_ERROR)
        message.ShowModal()
        message.Destroy()
        sys.exit(0)

except pywintypes.com_error:
    pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть библиотеки, в которых эта задача уже решена. Например, `tendo`, там решение кстати кросс-платформенноое.

Установка: `pip install tendo`

В скрипте делайте так:

```py
from tendo import singleton

# При повторном запуске тут вылетит ошибка
me = singleton.SingleInstance()
```

[Сcылки на исходник](https://github.com/pycontribs/tendo/blob/master/tendo/singleton.py), если интересно.